# Display name in URL from sql

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am having a list of members in my database, which i want to display in my website.

I am using php GET method, and the sample url is

```
com/members.php?id=454418
```

Can anyone please help me in getting url like

```
com/members/454418/steve-jobs
```

Comment: You have to look into [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.htaccess` file..

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

in this example:

com/members/454418

`$_GET['url']` = 454418

give it a try..

Answer (score 0):

You need to use URL rewriting.

Please check the [Apache URL Rewriting Guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html).